# Webhook limitations in linkedin API (webhook is not receiving updates)

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIN has recently released  support for webhooks and we are successful in creating a webhook url. We are able to authorise a user administrator of a company to our app and get permissions to write and read from the REST API.

However we are not receiving any webhook updates from the app for that company. And there is no documentation on how to subscribe to a particular company like in other social-media API:s witch we have vast experience from (fb,IG,Twitter).

The documentation on LinkedIn is very limited on the subject. And we are not sure what we can expect from the webhook requests from linkedIn. What is the reason we are not getting Webhooks for that company?

We dont even get webhook calls for the organisation owning the app.

Any help appreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/webhook-validation?context=linkedin/context

Comment: what is Hex-encoded function ? in my case testing webhook url has failed can you tell me how you have encoded challengeResponse what is the technology used for webhook

Comment: @Satya you just need add json content header to response

Comment: @Ali Akbar Azizi, in my case, webhook url has failed.I already add json content in response's header,
The client_secret is the setting's value of my application https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/[application_id]/webhooks
Please see below a part of code php that I use for validation.
$challengehex= hash_hmac('sha256', $challengeCode, $application_id);
$challengeResponse =  bin2hex($challengehex) ; 
$result = array('challengeCode' => $challengeCode , 'challengeResponse' => $challengeResponse);
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($result);

Comment: @user3323940 just remove `bin2hex` and you are fine, i also added my php sample code in answer

Comment: @Ali Akbar Azizi it works thank you, would you give me the form of the request because I always have  as response bad request "Syntax exception in path variables", here is the request : PUT https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn:li:developerApplication:{developer application ID},user:urn:li:user:{member ID},entity:urn:li:organization:{organization ID},eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)

Comment: @user3323940 i put my code in my answer, I use

Comment: @Ali Akbar Azizi ok it works well, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I figure it out I need to add header json to output for validation.
Here is my code in php

```php
if (isset($_REQUEST['challengeCode'])) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode([
        'challengeCode' => $_REQUEST['challengeCode'],
        'challengeResponse' => hash_hmac('sha256', $_REQUEST['challengeCode'], 'client secret'),
    ]);
    exit;
}
```

and for webhook subscription

```
$api->setApiHeaders([
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0',
]);
$developerUrn = urlencode("urn:li:developerApplication:developerid");
$personUrn = urlencode("urn:li:person:personid");
$orgUrn = urlencode(""urn:li:organization:pageid");
$endpoint = "(developerApplication:$developerUrn,user:$personUrn,entity:$orgUrn,eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)";

$api->api("eventSubscriptions/$endpoint", ['webhook' => "WEBHOOK_URL"], 'PUT');
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I followed your suggestion, even copy paste your code, but still failed validation of the url. Would you tell me what's the value of application_id that you've used as client_secret please. Is there other action that I have to do?thank you

Comment: @user3323940 sorry for wrong placeholder, i fixed that. its your Client Secret that come from app setting in Linkedin developer

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks are a closed beta feature at this time:

> Who can use this: Any developer using a webhooks API (currently available only for social action notifications on company posts to beta partners)

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/recent-changes

Comment: "Currently available only for social action notifications on company posts to beta partners" - Can we request for the webhooks API access?